# Stretch div size to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create my first web page. But I have a problem, I searched a lot about it but I still cannot solve it. So, the problem is, that my `div` (which is something like a background for the left side of the page, it has no content, only coloured background) is not stretching to the bottom of the page, it just stretches to the bottom of the screen, so when I scroll down the div is missing from there.
It looks like this (http://postimg.org/image/aiiabtue1/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>   
    <div class="left_strip"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left_strip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 203px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 158px;
    background: rgb(251, 236, 236);
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: relative` on the body tag and `bottom: 0` instead of `height: 100%` on the `.left_strip`.

With just `position: relative` on the body tag the element will be 100% height, but because of the `158px` distance from the top the bottom will be `158px` below the content.

`bottom: 0` will fix the bottom of the element to the bottom of the closest "positioned" (relative, absolute, fixed) parent element.

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.left_strip {
    position:absolute;
    width:203px;
    top: 158px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.content {
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="left_strip">Test content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using % try using the exact pixel value of the body tag.
What also might help is using a % value that is higher than 100, this also seems to work in testing.